# Hub events not available

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I am getting the following error when trying to subscribe to a SignalR hub event:

> $.connection.hub.connectionSlow is not a function

My code:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();
serviceRequestHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('myHub');
connection.start()
  .done(function () { alert('connected!'); });
$.connection.hub.connectionSlow(function () {
  alert('connection slow!');
});
```

I am using SignalR 2.2. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're not using generated proxy, $.connection will not be available. You should change to.

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();
serviceRequestHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('myHub');

connection.start()
  .done(function () { alert('connected!'); });

connection.connectionSlow(function () {
    console.log('We are currently experiencing difficulties with the connection.')
});
```

Read [more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client)